# conjugate prior

Tags: statistics, bayesian

A class of sampling distribution is a conjugate family of a prior
distribution, if the posterior distribution belongs to the same family for all priors
and all samples.
Why is this phrase incorrect?

Comment: Because it's the prior and posterior distributions on the parameter(s) of the sampling distribution that must belong to the same family in order to be conjugate.  The sampling distribution itself need not belong to the same family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually one says a class of priors is a conjugate family for a sampling distribution if the posterior distribution belongs to the same family for all samples.  To speak of the sampling distribution and the posterior distribution as belonging to the same family, rather than of the prior and posterior distributions belonging to the same family, is not just wrong but weird.  **The samples belong to one space and the prior and posterior distributions are distributions on another space.**  For example, the parameter space for the family of Poisson distributions is the set of all positive numbers, whereas the samples are integer-valued.  One may have a Gamma prior and a Gamma posterior, but the samples remain integer-valued.  And "for all priors" is nonsense.

Comment: Request for clarification:  is it a requirement for two distributions to be defined on the same probability space in order to belong to the same family?  And is this condition never satisfied; e.g., a normal sampling distribution with known variance whose conjugate prior for the mean is also normal?

Comment: In some instances, such as a normal prior and a normal sampling distribution, the parameter space and the space from which the data come are the same.  But that is not generally true.

Comment: So I guess my point is that the sampling distribution *could* come from the same family as the prior and posterior, so what I wrote in my comment in response to the question is technically correct, yes?

Comment: But the phrase "if the posterior distribution belongs to the same family..." means "in _all_ cases in which the posterior distribution belongs to the same family...".  Mentioning just one such case, or several, doesn't prove it's true in all such cases.